# Smart Phone Fixed Nav Bar Not Closing after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got some great info from this forum and this is my first question so be nice..

I have a top nav bar which is fixed.

The fixed part seems to be working fine but i now have two issues.

In responsive mode when you click the hamburger icon it opens beautifully and you can jump to any anchor on the page ( i am designing a 1 page site). But the nav wont close upon click or tap so i am left with a gaping open nav.

Second problem is when the nav is fixed and i scroll down and go over a form the form fields are displayed on top of the nav bar, in both 960 width & responsive.

I have attached what i think is the code here and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Max

This is the html:

```
<nav class="clearfix">
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="index.html"><span style="color:white">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="book.html"><span style="color:white">Book</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#join"><span style="color:white">Join</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html"><span style="color:white">Contact</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <a href="#" id="pull"><span style="color:white">Menu</span></a>
```

This is the css:

```
/* Clearfix */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
content: " ";
display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
*zoom: 1;
}
/* Basic Styles */

nav {
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
background: #455868;
font-size: 1em;
font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
position: fixed;
border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
width: auto;
height: 40px;
}
nav li {
display: inline;
float: none;
}
nav a {
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
width: 120px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 40px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #303030;
}
nav li a {
border-right: 1px solid #576979;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
background-color: #8c99a4;
}
nav a#pull {
display: none;
}
/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
nav {
    height: auto;
}
nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
nav li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;
}
nav a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 25px;
}
}
/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
}
nav a#pull {
    display: block;
    background-color: #283744;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
nav a#pull:after {
    content: "";
    background: url('../images/nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
}
}
/*Smartphone*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
nav li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
}
}
```

This is the java script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(function() {
        var pull = $('#pull');
        menu = $('nav ul');
        menuHeight = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function() {
            var w = $(window).width();
            if (w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML seems incomplete even for navigation menu. There isn't anything about JavaScript. Please mention if JavaScript is used or not. If used add the JavaScript code. Linking the forum is good idea. You can try creating a fiddle in jsfiddle.net to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first question add this js:

```
$('nav li>a').on('click', function (e) {
   if($(window).width()<600){
     menu.slideUp();
   }
 });
```

the full code is below:

```js
$(function() {
  var pull = $('#pull');
  menu = $('nav ul');
  menuHeight = menu.height();

  $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
  });

  $('nav li>a').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
      menu.slideUp();
    }
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
      menu.removeAttr('style');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Clearfix */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
/* Basic Styles */

nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #455868;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #303030;
}
nav li a {
  border-right: 1px solid #576979;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
  background-color: #8c99a4;
}
nav a#pull {
  display: none;
}
/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav {
    height: auto;
  }
  nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;
  }
  nav a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 25px;
  }
}
/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav a#pull {
    display: block;
    background-color: #283744;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a#pull:after {
    content: "";
    background: url('../images/nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
  }
}
/*Smartphone*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  nav li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="index.html"><span style="color:white">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="book.html"><span style="color:white">Book</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#join"><span style="color:white">Join</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html"><span style="color:white">Contact</a>

    </li>
  </ul> <a href="#" id="pull"><span style="color:white">Menu</span></a>

</nav>
```

`ul>li>a` can be changed with a ID or class as you prefer.

For 2nd question add this css:

```
nav {
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
background: #455868;
font-size: 1em;
font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
position: fixed;
border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
text-align: center;
z-index: 99;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3so7ca7b/3/)